# Cannot disable the same option already selected

Tags: javascript, jquery

Suppose I have two `select`. I'm trying to disable the options already selected in one of the select available with the class `criterias`, for achieve this I wrote the following code, but it didn't work, what I did wrong?

```js
$('.criterias').on('change', function(event) {
  var id = $(event.target).val();
  $('#container').find('.criterias')
    .siblings('.criterias')
    .children('option[value=' + id + ']')
    .attr('disabled', true)
    .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <table>
     <tr> 
        <td>
            <select class="criterias form-control">
              <option value="11">test1'</option>
              <option value="12">test2</option>
              <option value="13">test3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>
            <select class="criterias form-control">
              <option value="11">test1'</option>
              <option value="12">test2</option>
              <option value="13">test3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
```

Comment: I placed your code in an executable snippet where you can see it works absolutely fine. Check to ensure you've included jQuery.js in the page properly, are running your JS code after the DOM has loaded and there is no errors in the console

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: @NagaSaiA unfortunately nope, I'm checking why here works and in my local pc not

Comment: @sfarzoso, browser?

Comment: @NagaSaiA Chrome, anyway, for what I saw this: `('#container').find('.criterias')
    .siblings('.criterias')` return length: 0, so seems like cannot find the other select with the same class

Comment: @NagaSaiA ok, the problem is the table, I updated the question, seems like siblings not works if the controls are inside a table

Comment: @sfarzoso, remove sibiling method, posted my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, remove sibling method

```js
$('.criterias').on('change', function(event) {
  var id = $(event.target).val();
  $('#container').find('.criterias')
    .children('option[value=' + id + ']')
    .attr('disabled', true)
    .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <div id="container">
  <table>
     <tr> 
        <td>
            <select class="criterias form-control">
              <option value="11">test1'</option>
              <option value="12">test2</option>
              <option value="13">test3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
        <td>
            <select class="criterias form-control">
              <option value="11">test1'</option>
              <option value="12">test2</option>
              <option value="13">test3</option>
            </select>
        </td>
      </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

codepen - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/daXVLr